# INNER JOIN Group Muito lento na consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um select no mysql que esta demorando muito para retornar os registros, reparei que isso ocorre depois que a tabela fica mais cheia.

- Esse select faz  4 INNER JOINS e pega o ultimo registro de cada id pertencente a coluna id_motorista com um **GROUP**, o script funciona perfeitamente mais é muito lento.

Existe alguma forma de melhorar isso e tornalo mais rapido, abaixo segue meu script

[image: minha tabela]

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT 
  g.idgps,g.lat,g.long,g.id_motorista,g.id_saida,a.start,a.hora_start,a.p_nome,a.p_tipo_veiculo,a.id_saida,a.title,a.id_veiculo,v.modelo,v.placa,v.cor,v.foto1,v.id_veiculo,m.nomecompleto,m.id,m.logo, 

 `idgps` FROM gps AS g
  INNER JOIN agenda_saidas AS a
  ON g.id_saida= a.id_saida 
  INNER JOIN veiculos AS v
  ON a.id_veiculo = v.id_veiculo 
  INNER JOIN motoristas AS m
  ON g.id_motorista = m.id 
  WHERE `idgps` IN (SELECT MAX(`idgps`)FROM gps GROUP BY id_motorista)");
```

Comment: Imagino que os campos "id" têm índices, seria um problema óbvio. Subconsultas costumam dar muito problema de performance, seria legal testar a performance da subconsulta sozinha, e depois da consulta principal com uma lista fixa depois do IN, para ver se sozinhas elas desempenham.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: O problema não está no seu INNER JOIN, considerando que estes joins estejam relacionados a Foreign Keys e Primarys. A lentidão irá ocorrer devido ao seu IN e sua Subquery - GROUP BY "deve" ser utilizado somente para funções como SUM, COUNT, etc, evite o seu uso, procure utilizar ORDER com LIMIT e o seu MAX já restringe o resultado a 1 registros, então utilize " = " ao invés de IN, otimize seu WHERE. Cole um EXPLAIN da sua consulta para poder auxiliar onde está seu gargalo.

Answer (score 1):

Use um SELECT sem subquery isso vai aumentar muito o desempenho:

```
SELECT
  MAX(g.idgps), /*Esta agregação faz parte da mágica*/
  g.lat,
  g.long,
  g.id_motorista,
  g.id_saida,
  a.start,
  a.hora_start,
  a.p_nome,
  a.p_tipo_veiculo,
  a.id_saida,
  a.title,
  a.id_veiculo,
  v.modelo,
  v.placa,
  v.cor,
  v.foto1,
  v.id_veiculo,
  m.nomecompleto,
  m.id,
  m.logo
  /*`idgps` -> Não entendi, então comentei*/
FROM gps g
INNER JOIN agenda_saidas a  ON g.id_saida = a.id_saida 
INNER JOIN veiculos      v  ON a.id_veiculo = v.id_veiculo 
INNER JOIN motoristas    m  ON g.id_motorista = m.id
GROUP BY m.id /*Isto aqui faz a segunda parte da mágica*/
```